# How to use Stata inlist and ustrregexm functions in R?

Tags: r, stata, dplyr, grepl

I am trying to replace column `program` based on other columns `purposecode projecttitle shortdescription longdescriptionsee`. If an observation has a specific `purposecode`and contains a certain string in columns `projecttitle shortdescription longdescriptionsee` then it should contain (e.g.) `"forest"` in the column.

If it has a specific `purposecode` and does contain the string, which is identified by the outcome of the `grepl()` function being True, then the observation should be replaced by `"3"` in the 'program' column.

Here the code used in Stata:

```
foreach i in projecttitle shortdescription longdescription {
    replace program=3 if program==. & inlist(purposecode, 410, 41010, 41020, 41030, 41040, 41050, 41081, 41082) & (ustrregexm(`i',"forest",1)|ustrregexm(`i',"wald",1)| ustrregexm(`i',"forêt",1)|ustrregexm(`i',"bosque",1)|ustrregexm(`i',"floresta",1)| ustrregexm(`i',"biodiver",1))
}
```

I tried to use `mutate` and `grepl`  one by one for each `purposecode` because I don't know how to combine, but I got an error message:

```
"Error in FUN(left, right) : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"
```

Code I used:

```
df$program[df$purposecode == "410"
& mutate(.data = df, REDD_VS = case_when(grepl("forest", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("wald", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("bosque", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("floresta", projecttitle) ~ "3", grepl("biodiver", projecttitle) ~ "3"))
& mutate(.data = df, program = case_when(grepl("forest", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("wald", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("bosque", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("floresta", shortdescription) ~ "3", grepl("biodiver", shortdescription) ~ "3"))
& mutate(.data = df, program = case_when(grepl("forest", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("wald", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("forêt", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("bosque", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("floresta", longdescription) ~ "3", grepl("biodiver", longdescription) ~ "3"))] <- 3
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I've tried to tidy this up, but please check that your meaning is preserved.  As I often remark, asking for a translation is often too indirect and assumes that people likely to answer are fluent in Stata as well as R. You're better advised to say directly what you have in R, what you have tried and what the immediate problem is. How to do it in Stata is not so relevant; there is a rarely a word by word or even sentence by sentence translation.  Asking for a reproducible example really is Lesson 1 here.

Comment: Both your R and Stata codes could be made much more readable by using OR within a *single* regular expressions rather than using many individual elements (e.g., something like `ustrregexm(\`i',"forest|wald|forêt|bosque|floresta|biodiver",1)`).